# C++ : vector standard template library

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stack, dynamic-arrays

In C++ STL vector is a dynamic array, but it performs operations like a stack. So can any one please tell whether data is stored in stack or heap segment.

Comment: Since is dynamic array as you said then I suppose in the heap.

Comment: *Any* memory can function as a stack, it's just a matter of where you add and remove elements.

Comment: what do you mean by "it performs operations like a stack"?. I mean like stack data structure or local array defined on stack.

Comment: Also, you need to differ between the concepts of a stack data structure and stack memory, they are two different and orthogonal concepts.

Comment: It performs like a stack data structure @MantoshKumar

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` itself doesn't define how the memory it uses is allocated. It does memory allocation via an Allocator object.

By default, a `vector<T>` will use an `std::allocator<T>` to handle allocation. That, in turn, will use `operator new` and `operator delete` to allocate/delete memory.

Those are all subject to change though--the type for the Allocator is passed to `vector` as a template parameter, so if you want to write an Allocator class that does allocation differently, you're entirely free to do that. Assuming it meets the requirements on an allocator, you can then create instances of `std::vector` that use your allocator instead of the default one.

You can also provide replacements for `operator new` and `operator delete` on a class-by-class and/or global basis. If you do so, `std::allocator<T>` will use your allocation/deletion routines instead of those defined in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

It's stores it's elements in a contiguous block on the heap.  It can be locally created or dynamically allocated.  And finally even a simple c-style array can be used as a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Anything stored in a Vector is stored in contiguous memory in the heap.
It is also not designed to act as a stack, although you could use it to implement stack operations, it is (probably) more effiecient to use an actual stack implementation in that case.*

It is worth noting that the memory used by a Vector can be changed as adding or removing elements can cause it to re-allocate memory.

*If you pre-allocate memory beforehand, then most implementations of a stack will be roughly as efficent as any other.

Answer (score 0):

"

```
vector<Type> vect;
```

will allocate the vector, i.e. the header info, on the stack, but the elements on the free store ("heap").

```
vector<Type> *vect = new vector<Type>;
```

allocates everything on the free store.

```
vector<Type*> vect;
```

will allocate the vector on the stack and a bunch of pointers on the free store, but where these point is determined by how you use them (you could point element 0 to the free store and element 1 to the stack, say)."

Your question is answered by larsmans at 7-11-11.Your welcome.